# finding the column value * using awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk

Currently, I have a file with multiple columns and on my 4,5th columns, the null values are displayed as *

I have tried

```sh
awk '{if ($4==/*) {print}}' filename
awk '{if ($4==\*) {print}}' filename
awk '{if ($4=='*') {print}}' filename
awk '{if ($4=='\*') {print}}' filename
awk '{if ($4=='/*/') {print}}' filename
```

for

```sh
awk '{if ($4=='/*/') {print}}' filename
awk '{if ($4==/*/) {print}}' filename
```

they run, but does not print out anything (but I know there are * values in the file)

and rest they are getting a syntax error or regex error

what can I do to fix this???

Answer (score 2):

`awk` strings are enclosed in double quotes. The `awk` script is normally put in single quotes, and if you also use single quotes around the `awk` strings, they would terminate the shell string, not delimit the awk string (and shell single quotes don't provide any escaping mechanism).

```
awk '$4 == "*"' filename
```

The condition for processing a line is put before the action, and if there's no action block the default is to print the line. So this the above is equivalent to:

```
awk '{if ($4 == "*") print}' filename
```

Comment: If you really waoted to, you could use a regex; `if ($4 ~ '/^\*$/)`. I don't recommend this; I'm just pointing out how to properly use slashes. Notice the `~` operator instead of `==` and the backslash to escape the asterisk, which is otherwise a metacharacter in regex.

Comment: Maybe also explain how `if($4=='*')` gets passed in as `if ($4==*)` (which is obviously a syntax error) once the shell has handled the single quotes and Awk is about to start executing.

Comment: @tripleee I've added a sentence about how the single quotes terminate the shell string.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk pattern to implement the condition

```
awk '$4 == "*" || $5 == "*" { print }'

Or Even
awk '$4 == "*" || $5 == "*"'
```

Comment: You aren't using _patterns_

Comment: In 'awk' programs, each statement is consider 'pattern { action-statement }'. Pattern can be REGEX, expressions, etc. Not referring to bash file name pattern.

Comment: got it. the man page does indeed refer to those conditionals as _patterns_, didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function `index()`:

```
awk 'index($4""$5, "*")' file
```

`index(s, t)` is returning the position of the substring `t` in `s` or `0` if `t` was not found in `s`.

The program above is using the `index()` function as a condition. `awk` will print the current line if that condition becomes true-ish. `0`, not found, is false-ish in awk. A more explicit version of the above program would be:

```
awk '{if(index($4""$5, "*") != 0){print}}' file
```